# Visual Studio 2019 "Open With..." BimlExpress Files Error "The Parameter is incorrect"

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, biml

I cannot open any biml files in VS2019.

When I attempt to open or designate with "Open With..." I am presented with an error.

- I've restarted windows.
- Un/re-installed VS2019.
- Microsoft DataTools and BimlExpress.

And the issue won't clear up. Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

1. Closed Visual Studio 2019
2. Renamed from IDE to IDE_old in folder in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7
3. Reinstalled bimlexpress.vsix
4. Opened Visual Studio 2019
5. Working